# export table to csv file with COPY in postgres and suggestion to reduce the csv file size

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I am trying to exporting table in Postgres DB into csv file with COPY command and the result csv file size is very large.

Below is the command for export them into csv file.

Actual table size is: 600MB
Result csv file size: 162MB

Command:

```
\copy cities to '/var/lib/pgsql/cities.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Could someone please advise how to reduce the size of the csv file?

Is it default behavior of COPY command?
Can we reduce the size of the file?

Comment: The only way to reduce the size is to export fewer rows or fewer columns. But if you need all the data, I don't see a way to reduce the size

Comment: You could compress the CSV file with zip or bzip or a similar tool.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name and Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the file on the fly:

```
\copy cities TO PROGRAM 'gzip -9 > /var/lib/pgsql/cities.csv.gz' (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT 'csv', HEADER)
```

Comment: I could able to export the table data into a CSV file, but the exported CSV file size around 162MB.
While I am trying to opening the excel it is taking a long time and also while applying vlookup on excel is getting hang.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the following things with COPY command :
1. The exported csv file should have within 10MB.
2. The excel file should open quickly and able to perform vlookups without any problems(like hang).

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the above things in my use case?

Comment: Then your only option is to export fewer data.

Comment: This didn't work for me. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'gzip -9 > ./myfile.csv.gz'"`
`LINE 1: COPY  ttempo TO STDOUT 'gzip -9 > ./myfile.csv.gz' (DELI...`

Answer (score 0):

You can compress it afterwards.  Or you can compress it on the fly:

```
\copy cities to PROGRAM 'gzip > /var/lib/pgsql/cities.csv.gz' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Of course you could replace `gzip` with `pigz` or `bzip2` or `pxz` or whatever your favorite streaming compressor is.

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'gzip > /var/lib/pgsql/cities.csv.gz'`

Comment: @arilwan don't use versions which predate the dinosaurs.

Comment: `SELECT version()`
`PostgreSQL 9.6.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.16-1.pgdg18.04+1),` `compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7`
.`4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit`

Comment: It is the version of `psql`, not the server, that matters here.